# How to export from mercurial to fossil?

Tags: mercurial, fossil

I need something of a bug tracker to manage my small one-person project. I decided to use fossil. My project is on bitbucket mercurial repo. Unfortunately fossil docs contain the information about git to fossil export only.

How can I export (convert) it to fossil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Fossil can [import](https://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/help?cmd=import) from Git's fast-export or SVN's dump
- In order to import Mercurial repo, you have previously push it to Git (with hg-git) or SVN (with hgsubversion)